# Do the Stack Exchange sites have central control?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

When a certain site on SE says something like 'the site is run by you', does it mean there is no central control or the rules are determined by whichever group of people with the highest reputation and badges?

Comment: That phrase is more along the lines of there are site moderators, but regular users can also moderate content. Let me give you an example of how that phrase works. Once upon a time, certain questions didn't get hit as hard when they were asked here. They weren't considered that bad a thing. Then, as time went on, regular users decided they didn't agree with that. They came and talked about it on Meta, and after a community consensus was reached, those questions were deemed "off-topic" and hit harder by moderation.

Comment: @Kendra - site moderators are elected by the community and come from the community too.

Comment: @Oded Right! I didn't think to mention that. Thanks! :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins

Comment: I think this question belongs in [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) since it isn't particularly about stackoverflow.

Comment: That's marketing speech for: you deliver the content, we deliver the framework. In the same way Facebook or Twitter is run by the users.

Comment: @Trilarion users on SE sites have a lot more "power" than those on Facebook/Twitter... We do a lot more moderation of the content

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, of course there is central control.

Stack Exchange has set down the basic rules, employees help moderate, etc. We also have elected moderators (from the community) with super-powers.

The statement "This site is run by you" means that *every user* is also a moderator, just different in what they can do. We moderate by voting, commenting, closing, and flagging. We even get shiny badges for doing so!

Also, to a certain extent, the community as a whole (certainly not just high rep users, though they are more likely to be involved) sets the standards for what is on-topic, high quality, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The Stack Exchange team have full access, including the rights to ban, set sites in 'offline mode', and removal/adding of moderator rights to a user.

The most basic hierarchy for any Stack Exchange site is Stack Exchange Staff -> Moderators -> 'Super' Users (those with elevated rights such as reviews) -> Standard Users (users with no extended privileges)

As BradleyDotNET mentioned in his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276782), the phrase *The site is run by you* refers to the fact that ***every user*** has some degree moderation tools, be it the simple flags/voting, review queues, to full moderator privileges.

The basic rules of each Stack Exchange site are set-down by the Stack Exchange team, but however moderators are able to change them (usually as a result of a well-received request from a user on Meta).
An example of this on Stack Overflow is that in the first couple of years of the site being online, software questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757594/what-is-the-best-choice-for-a-corporate-wiki-blog-software-tool) (users need 10k+ to view) were on-topic. However now these questions are off-topic as the community decided that it didn't want these questions anymore, and moderators changed the rules.

The one thing that moderators ***cannot do*** is put a Stack Exchange site into read-only mode; only the Stack Exchange staff can do this.

So yes, there is central control at Stack Exchange staff level.

Comment: There are lots of things Moderators cannot do. They cannot see who voted for what and how. They cannot merge users. They cannot lift post-bans.

Comment: I knew it. Someone is watching me voting...